# Creating API Resource Using Laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, doctrine

Below is my data, I want to create API Resource using this-

```
array:1 [
  0 => JobPosted {#2635
    -id: 1
    -jobTitle: "Business Development Executive"
    -noOfPosition: 1
    -experience: "2-5"
    -jobLocation: "Mumbai"
    -jobSkill: "Good communication skill, knowledge of Mandarin"
    -jobDescription: "Good communication skill, knowledge of Mandarin"
    -isClosed: false
    -isActive: true
  }
]
```

I am using doctrine with laravel.
My JobResource is as

```
public function toArray($request){
        return [
            'jobTitle' => $this->getJobTitle(),
            'noOfPosition' => $this->getNoOfPosition(),
            'experience' => $this->getExperience(),
            'jobLocation' => $this->getJobLocation(),
            'jobSkills' => $this->getJobSkill(),
            'jobDescription' => $this->getJobDescription()
        ];
    }
```

and JobResourceCollection is as

```
 public function toArray($request){
            return parent::toArray($request);
        }
```

and JobController is as

```
public function getJobs(Request $request){
  $jobs = $this->jobPostedService->getJobPosted($limit);
  return response()->json(new JobResourceCollection($jobs), 200);
}
```

after executing this I'm getting error as

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Call to a member function first() on array

Comment: Please the getJobPosted method on the  jobpostedservice

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue by using

```
 public function getJobs(Request $request){
  $jobs = $this->jobPostedService->getJobPosted($limit);
  return response()->json(new JobResourceCollection(collect($jobs)), 200);
}
```

instead of

```
public function getJobs(Request $request){
  $jobs = $this->jobPostedService->getJobPosted($limit);
  return response()->json(new JobResourceCollection($jobs), 200);
}
```